# Puppeteer Cant Ignore Network Interface

Tags: networking, centos, puppeteer, chromium

Have Centos 7 with node ,puppeteer and all dependencies installed..
And i have two ips with two network interface.

Server Ip : x.x.x.100

Additional ip: x.x.x.11

With request module, i can specify localAdress value to determine which ip address should be used for that request and it works properly.

But, when i use simple puppeteer script to grab ip screenshot, it always throw additional ip.

```
ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1
  
2: ens32: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
   
3: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
```

I tried **"--netifs-to-ignore=ens160"** arg and tried both for ens32 and ens160 but still getting additional ip adress.

Desired result:

I will run two puppeteer with two node script, one of them should launch chromium with main ip, and other should launch with additional ip, So i will connect to web with two ips.

Comment: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6744